# CSS transition vs jQuery .animation() vs JS toggling classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm a newbie trying to create an **animated mobile menu** and I'm wondering if there's a better approach to this.

My nav menu is in a `<ul>` that is **hidden off screen** by default (`right: -100vw`) and I have an unused class `.open` which has the rule `right: 0`. I also have a unique `transition-delay` on each `<li>` in my `<ul>`.

So,

```
ul { right: -100vw; transition:right 1s; }
.open { right: 0; }
li:nth-of-type(2) { transition-delay: 0.5s; }
```

When user **clicks** on mobile-menu-hamburger-icon, **toggle the class `.open` on the `<ul>`**.

**It functions, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach**. I recognize I can instead take the route of creating a CSS animation (`@keyframes`) and triggering it on hamburger-click via JS. Or, I can also just use jQuery's `animate()` to do all the work.

Would love to hear thoughts or guidance!

Comment: Consider editing your post to remove all words like "better". Some users close posts as opinion based due to this. Perhaps try to just rephrase to ask if there's another way. Don't ask for advice or guidance as that's also a trigger for closing as opinion based.

Comment: @Faheel It's unfortunate that this post was edited. Now the Question author has be deprived of their only entry into the reopen queue with just a cosmetic edit :(

Comment: @Scratte Yeah, it's unfortunate. I submitted an edit to improve its formatting within 10 minutes of it being posted, hoping that it would attract more readers. Can this question not be re-opened now?

Comment: @Faheel I didn't close it. I also didn't raise a flag on it. I explained my suspicions in the first comment. Any edit to this post later than the final outcome from the reopen-queue will lead nowhere. Consider not making cosmetic edits to posts that may get closed.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is just a state change (`right` value), You can use `transition` only.
It is also doable in animation but it will just add more lines of code which can be achieved in a simpler way. Animation is just an abstraction of transition and both uses hardware-acceleration, so there won't be any performance difference, though.